# Can xpaths be copied and pasted directly into beautiful soup parsers, or must they be modified?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I want to extract the PMID (i.e. the number '23410195') from [this](http://isyslab.info/NeuroPep/search_info?pepNum=NP00001) webpage.

I got the xpath in firefox by looking at the page source, right clicking on the element I want, and click paste xpath, into this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import lxml
from lxml import etree
from lxml import html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
output_file = open('neuropep.txt', 'a')
from urllib.request import urlopen

for i in range(1,2):
#       try:
                number = '{:05}'.format(i)
                url = 'http://isyslab.info/NeuroPep/search_info?pepNum=NP' + str(number)
                response = urlopen(url)
                htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
                tree = etree.parse(response,htmlparser)
                var = tree.xpath('/html/body/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[14]/td[2]/ol/li/p/span/a')
                print(var)
```

But the output is just an empty list?

I tried some other non-successful methods: e.g.

```
               content = requests.get(url)
               soup = bs(content.content,'lxml')
               /html/body/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[14]/td[2]/ol/li/p/span/a
               table = soup.find_all('table')
               print(table[0])
```

I'm just wondering what's up here? Specifically, why when I copy and paste the xpath of an element, why the output is an empty list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pmid` is injected to the page through Javascript.

You can use `selenium` to extract it, or `re` module:

```
import re
import requests

url = 'http://isyslab.info/NeuroPep/search_info?pepNum=NP00001'

m = re.findall(r"var reference = String\('(\d+)", requests.get(url).text)

if m:
    print(m[0])
```

Prints:

```
23410195
```

Answer (score 0):

You would not need to specify the absolute xpath. Use relative xpath to identify the PMID.
In this particular website, they have made it easy by enclosing the PMID inside a `span`

You can try something like `.//span[@id='pmid']/a`

Answer (score 0):

if you right click on the page and select "view page source" option you'll see if what you are looking for is being displayed dynamically or if it is there in the raw html page source and most importantly if it is there to begin with or not. In this case the number is not in html but it is available in a script tag. so you'll have to adjust your logic accordingly.